# quadric surfaces. Uniqueness theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratic-forms

I would like to know references (book or monograph) for this theorem about quadric surfaces.
If $F(x)=0$ is an equation in $K[x]$ of a quadric surface $C$ and
i) ${\rm char}(K) \not= 2$
ii) $C$ has a regular point 
Then every equation of $C$ is a multiple of $F(x)$